# how to use getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am new in next.js. Recently,I learned about pre-render in next.js,and I am confused about how to update props data from getServerSideProps

_app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

/pages/tasks/list.tsx

Comment: It has been describe very detail in the docs [data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to use GetServerSideProps :

```
//'pages/index.js'

// Extraction des articles reçus via les props
// Props extraction 
export default function Home({articles}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {articles.map((el, key) => (
                <div key={key}>
                    <p>{JSON.stringify(el)}</p>

                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {

    // Fetching de notre route
    // API fetching
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/yourApiRoutes')

    // Récupération des données de notre requête
    // Cast value to json object
    const articles = await res.json()

    return {
        // Approvisionnement des props de notre page
        // Sending articles to page
        props: {articles: articles}
    }
}
```

Hope I could help !